# How to load other pages by links opening webview app instead of home or main page

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using webview to make my website as an android application. It works fine.

```
mywebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = mywebView.getSettings();
mywebView.loadUrl("https://mywebsite.com/");
```

As I implemented a share system on my website to share some articles and when we click on a link which supposed to open the app with shared link if the app is installed, if not it opens the playstore to download it.

The type of link I used :

```
<a style="font-size: 25px;" href="intent:#Intent;scheme=myscheme://open;package=com.mypackage.package;S.browser_fallback_url=https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mypackage.package;end">Article 1</a>
```

So only problem is it always opens the main page.

Like if an user clicks on a link say `https://mywebsite.com/article_1.php` from browser it opens `https://mywebsite.com/`.

What I want is to open the right page (**here article_1.php**) referenced in the shared link opening the webview application instead of the main page (**mywebsite.com**).

Any ideas? How do i fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Deep link` on your app.

first of all add `view` action to your activity that want to be open on link clicks in manifest.

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
```

and add `DEFAULT` & `BROWSABLE` category for access from web browser and handle intent.

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

then add your data tag

```
<data
    android:host="mywebsite.com"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

in activity you define that codes you can achieve data by this codes:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri data = intent.getData();
```

now you can parse the link and handle your logic.

The full documentation can be found here:

> [Create Deep Links to App Content](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking)

hope it help you.

Comment: thanks to this. All works fine, links open the app with the right page. But when the app is already running, the deeplink don't work. I mean it opens the app but no loading the url in the deeplink. Any ideas?

Comment: you put last code in wrong place. put that in `onResume()` method.  if answer was helpful you can use upvote button and mark the question as solve.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what code you're talking about, can you explain more clear.

Comment: Ok I understand. So in onResume() method, I have to put the last code and also to call the loadUrl() function with the new uri. That's what I did to make it work as I want. Thanks.